# What greetings are appropriate on Pesach Sheni?

Tags: minhag, passover

Are standard Passover greetings appropriate for Pesach Sheni? E.g. חג פסח שמח? Or just חג שמח because it's not Passover proper? I'm guessing "gut yontiff" would not be appropriate as it is not a yom tov?

Comment: Do you mean back in the day when people still brought korbanot on that day, or do you mean today? I've never heard anyone say anything special on Pesach Sheni, would be interested if somewhere they do

Comment: Pesach Sheni hasn't meant anything halachically in about 2000 years (since Megillat Taanit was nullified). While there are some recent customs innovated (mostly by chasidim) to acknowledge the historical importance of the day, I've never heard of anyone using a special greeting.

Comment: In some years (in particular, years when the upcoming Shavuot starts on Monday), the Ashkenazi tradition is to greet people with "have an easy fast" on Pesach Sheni.

Comment: This year an appropriate greeting would be ah guten erev Shabbos

Comment: Pesach Sheni is not considered a chag (or at least not "מקודש לחג", namely, per Rashi's explanation, that it's not a Yom Tov, see [P'sachim 95b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.95b.2?lang=bi)): "א"ר יוחנן משום ר' שמעון בן יהוצדק אמר קרא (ישעיהו ל, כט) השיר יהיה לכם כליל התקדש חג לילה המקודש לחג טעון הלל לילה שאין מקודש לחג אין טעון הלל".